# Laravel выборка по главной и связанной таблице

Tags: laravel5, eloquent

есть модель занятий Lesson

```
 public function teacher()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(LessonTeacher::class, 'lesson_id');
  }
```

И модель с преподавателями LessonTeacher

```
 public function lesson()
  {
     return $this->belongsTo(Lesson::class,'id');
  }
```

Я ввожу в форме дату и преподавателя и отправляю AJAX запрос в контроллер. Я хочу узнать не занят ли преподаватель в дату который ввел пользователь в форму. С датой проблем нет, а вот с поиском преподавателя выходит ошибка

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::teacher does not exist
```

Сам запрос

```
$check_lesson_date = Lesson::where(function($query) use ($date_start) {
          return $query->where('date_start', '<=', $date_start)->where('date_end', '>=', $date_start);
      })
      ->orWhere(function($query) use ($date_end) {
          return $query->where('date_start', '<=', $date_end)->where('date_end', '>=', $date_end);
      })
      ->get();



 $check_teacher = $check_lesson_date->teacher()->where('teacher', $teacher)->count();
```

Подскажите что я делаю не так и как правильно составить запрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать `whereHas` метод, а сейчас получается вы берёте коллекцию и пытаетесь из неё обратиться к реляции.

```
$teacherName = ''; // Ваша переменная $teacher.

$check_lesson_date = Lesson::whereHas('teacher', function ($query) use ($teacher) {
    $query->where('teacher', $teacher);
})->where(function($query) use ($date_start) {
    return $query->where('date_start', '<=', $date_start)->where('date_end', '>=', $date_start);
})
->orWhere(function($query) use ($date_end) {
    return $query->where('date_start', '<=', $date_end)->where('date_end', '>=', $date_end);
})
->exists();
```

Comment: Спасибо, понял, помогло) Только теперь возвращает undefined, но это уже другая история)